# Connecting to SQL Server from Mac via Actual Technologies's ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server, ruby, macos, odbc

Anyone out there successfully connect to SQL Server from 64bit Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) using Actual Technologies's [ODBC driver](http://www.actualtech.com/product_sqlserver.php)? I'm not interested in using the iODBC Unix driver.

For Ruby 1.8.7 I have:

- dbi (0.4.5)
- dbd-odbc (0.2.5)
- ruby-odbc (0.99992)

Here's my simple Ruby script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbi'

db = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:MyDSN', 'user', 'password')
begin
  result = db.execute('SELECT name FROM sys.databases')
  while row = result.fetch do
    puts row.to_s
  end
ensure
  db.disconnect if db
end
```

I've also tried this using ActiveRecord:

- activerecord (1.15.6)
- activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.0.5)

Script:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'activerecord'
require 'active_record'
require 'logger'
```

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'sqlserver',
    :mode => 'odbc',
    :dsn => 'MyDSN',
    :username => 'user',
    :password => 'password'
)

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SELECT name FROM sys.databases'

while r = result.fetch_row
  puts r
end

However, on fetch, both the DBI and ActiveRecord examples error with a Segmentation fault:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:43: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10]
```

In Ruby 1.9.2 there's more error information:

```
/Users/ejstembler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10]
```

-- control frame ----------
c:0006 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 CFUNC  :fetch
c:0005 p:0014 s:0019 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /Users/ejstembler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41
c:0004 p:0139 s:0014 b:0014 l:000013 d:000013 METHOD /Users/ejstembler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb:220
c:0003 p:0102 s:0009 b:0009 l:001588 d:0001e0 EVAL   ss_dbi.rb:7
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH

### c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001588 d:001588 TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
ss_dbi.rb:7:in `<main>'
/Users/ejstembler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb:220:in`fetch'
/Users/ejstembler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41:in `fetch'
/Users/ejstembler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41:in`fetch'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

I'm not familiar with reading this type of error dump, however if I were to guess I would say that fetch is the last thing being called for it calls out to a C function (CFUNC). I'm not sure if the C function is part of a gem, the Ruby library, or the ODBC driver itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: It’s kind of sad that I can connect to SQL Server from my Mac via JRuby + JDBC. I’d like to avoid using Java and stick with pure Ruby.

Comment: I tried this using the FreeTDS and noticed statement.rb is still getting a Segmentation Fault.  Does this mean both ODBC drivers are faulty on Mac OS, or that dbd-odbc-0.2.5 is faulty, or odbc-ruby is faulty?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [OpenLink Rails ODBC Adapter](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/) and [ODBC Driver for SQL Server](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/view_solution.php?solutions_id=6415&solution_num=1) on Mac OS X which have specific enhancements for working with Ruby on Rails and have been tested on Mac OS X ?

Comment: I got a little further using ActiveRecord + OpenLink… However, I can’t seem to get results from ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute. It returns NilClass error.

Comment: Unfortunately the ODBC driver for SQL Server on Mac was only for 32bit PowerPC architecture. I’m on 64bit Intel (Snow Leopard).

Comment: I'm not sure what driver you were looking at, Edward...  The OpenLink driver for SQL Server is a universal build, which supports 32- and 64-bit binaries on both Intel and PPC hardware -- and had this same support at your time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out?

I'm using Ruby-ODBC and ActiveRecord on Windows to query a custom driver:

```
    require "sinatra/activerecord"
    require "odbc"
```

I wrote the following:

```
    maxwell = ODBC.connect("Maxwell")
    stmt = maxwell.run query
```

The DSN ("Maxwell") was configured globally (outside my Ruby app) and I didn't need to specify the driver, since this already was set in odbc.ini.